# var_dump inside wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, var-dump

**what I want to do:** my contact form 7 is very simple. I have a input field and a submit button. I want to manipulate the data from the textfield instead of (or maybe before, but for now just say, instead of) sending an email. let's say I want to add 1 to the number entered and display it on the screen.
my cf7:

```
[number* textfield]
[submit "Senden"]
```

**my functions.php:** at the end of my `functions.php`, i have the following code.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_datamanipulate");  
function wpcf7_datamanipulate($cf7) {
    $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    if (true) 
        $wpcf->skip_mail = true; 
    return $wpcf;
}
```

this works quite well for skipping the mail. perfekt. Now I want to `var_dump` or `print_r` the content of `$wpcf` so I know where the number is stored I entered earlier.

```
var_dump($wpcf);
```

doesn't seem to work in the `functions.php` - nor does a simple `echo`.

I also tried to kill the script right after `var_dump()` with `die()`, but the content of `$wpcf` isn't working.

what can I use to display the data I need to work with in my function?

thanks a lot!

Comment: where in your function, is your var_dump placed?

Comment: @stender, i tried it between the declaration of $wpcf and if(true) statements and before the return statement. neither of those position worked.

Answer (score 3):

When debugging functions.php I use the following:

```
echo "<!-- DEBUG\n" . print_r($wpcf, true) . "\n-->";
```

The above puts your print_r data inside a HTML comment, so the page will render as normal. Then just view the source of the page and search for `"DEBUG"`. You'll see your data.

The important bit is the `true` specified for `print_r`. This instructs print_r to **return** a string (which is appended to the comment string) and echo puts it into the html. Once the page is finished rendering, then you can view the comment.

Otherwise, print_r will try and print the data straight away and it may not end up where you want it (or cause that horrible headers have already been sent issue).

Comment: unfortunately this did not solve my problem. the content of $wpcf is nowhere to be found in the source code. the page contact form 7 plugin keeps loading. https://imgur.com/916mEgC

Comment: Are you viewing the HTML source of the page? That image is showing the rendered web page. In Google Chrome, right-click on the page and choose inspect. Then from in the Elements Tab, press ctrl+F to search. https://imgur.com/a/6yDk7

Comment: yes. i do view the source code of the page. and ctrl+f my way to find "debug"

Answer (score -1):

Echo from DukeOfAnkh's solution didn't work for me neither. I found [this article](https://www.securitydawg.com/changing-contact-form-7-with-the-wpcf7_before_send_mail-hook/) where is wrote "Note that you can’t ‘echo’ or ‘print’ anything to the screen in this process; it won’t be shown." and mentioned alternative worked:

`error_log( print_r( $WPCF7_ContactForm, 1 ) );`